# At the start of the New 52, how many people know the identity of Batman?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, batman

In the old continuity, quite a number of people ultimately knew Batman was Bruce Wayne. How has that changed with the re-launch of the New 52?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spolier Alert**

I've just started reading the series, but as far as I know despite his Bat Family (Alfred, Nightwing, Robin aka Damian, Redhood, BatGirl) no one else knew it in start. Joker seems to know it, but in the end of "Death in the Family" Bruce argued that Joker doesn't know and doesn't even want to know who's behind the mask, because it'll ruin the fun ;-)

Talons knew it in the Court of the Owl series, since they attacked his BatCave, but they learnt it by accident and it was not in the start of the series.

Later, the whole Justice League starting member knew it (obviously).

PS: I'll update the answer, as soon as I keep reading the comics.

Answer (score 2):

The extent of the changes made in the wake of the New 52 are still being revealed. We have to wait and see for the most part, although Batman is said to have suffered the least amount of changes.

It is certain that Catwoman no longer knows his identity. We have to wait for an appearance by other characters who knew his identity such as Riddler and Ra's to see if they still know or not.